# Importing non-existing file in LESS

Tags: import, less

I have a `styles.less` file that imports a `variables.less` file.

For theming purposes, I would like to have a `theme.less` file, which overrides the variables of `variables.less`.

My `styles.less` would look like

```
@import 'variables';
@import 'theme';

.my-class {
   background: @bg;
}
```

The issue comes when the `theme.less` file doesn't exist (i.e. if I do not want to apply any theme), since LESS exists the compilation process after throwing the error.

Is there a way to make less throw a warning if the file doesn't exist and continue compiling?

Comment: No, there's no way. See [#2145](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2145). The simplest suggestion is to provide just empty `theme.less` (probably even better in a directory where it could be easily overridden by real `theme.less` later).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

@import (optional) "foo.less";

font: http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature